# Java.io.FileNotFoundException when downloading file

Tags: java, android

I can't figure out whats the problem here, it used to work but not anymore. I am trying to download a file from an url. It seems i am not properly creating the file.

```
            static String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/com.xxxx.xxxx/";
            url = new URL("http://xxxxxxx.xxx/file.apk");
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(false);
            c.connect();


            File file = new File(PATH);
            File outputFile = new File(file, "update"+separated[1]+".apk");

            //it crashes at this point

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();


 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxxxx.xxx/update150.apk: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
    at com.sanisidrolsa.appterris.GcmIntentService.onHandleIntent(GcmIntentService.java:67)
    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Have you checked manually if file is getting downloaded correctly on correct location and the file name is also correct ? Please double check.

Comment: `file.mkdirs();` maybe to possibly create the directories?

Comment: change FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);  to OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

Comment: Oh... I forgot to change the file path when i changed the package name a while ago. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From Android 4.0, you can not make network or HTTP requests on the main thread, otherwise you get an [ANR](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) (Application Not Responding) error.

You need to put the HTTP request into a new thread. Because the high version of Android OS considers that asynchronous I/O requests, such as network or database, are better.

There are several techniques about async operations in Android OS.

Maybe [this](http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/) is helpful for you.

Comment: @MauriF   haha, the third party library is more convenient.   https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http